# use subquery in Cloudkit

Tags: ios, cloudkit

Anyone knows how to use subquery in CloudKit? Here is my trying code:

```
// stringArray is String list in Cloudkit
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(stringArray, $fS, ANY $fS = %@).@count != 0", targetString];
CKQuery *query = [[CKQuery alloc] initWithRecordType:@"TestRecord" predicate:predicate];
[publicDatabase performQuery:query inZoneWithID:nil completionHandler:^(NSArray *results, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"%@", results);
}];
```

But caught CKException and showed failed message `Expected key-path in comparison expression: SUBQUERY(stringArray, $fS, ANY $fS = "targetString").@count != 0`

Any idea or something wrong?

Comment: Here what is there $fS referring to?

Comment: string in stringArray

Comment: Try with some hardcoded targetString : SUBQUERY(stringArray, $fS, ANY $fS = "AnyStringFromStringArray").@count != 0

Comment: What is error code for that exception?

Comment: `failed: caught "CKException", "Expected key-path in comparison expression: SUBQUERY(stringArray, $fS, ANY $fS == "AnyStringFromStringArray").@count != 0"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67407/discussion-between-mrunal-and-scott).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the documentation about NSPredicates for CloudKit.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CloudKit/Reference/CKQuery_class/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/cl/CKQuery

As you can see it only allows a subset of what you can do for the full NSPredicate class. Subqueries and aggregates (like the .@count) are not allowed.

Comment: Thanks. I just also found same content in the header of CKQuery.